References for Weil restriction?
I'm reading some people's notes and some fantastic answers on stackexchange on Weil restriction. I don't have a background in algebraic geometry, so some of the simplified versions, particularly of $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$ have been particularly helpful. However, I am writing an essay and would like some reputable references that I could use (I don't think MSE or MOF answers would fly with my prof). A lot of places reference Neron models, but I've had a look at it and he talks about Weil restriction in way more generality than I need with way too much geometry and homology background. I was wondering if I could get any other references for Weil restriction. Thank you!

Well I imagine there are numerous books that include passages on Weil restriction but in my opinion Bjorn Poonen's book "Rational points on varieties " has a (rather short) but very concise exposition of Weil restriction on Chapter 4, 4.6, without the mention of Neron models and with further references for more detailed proofs.

That has just the perfect amount I need, thank you so very much!

You are very welcome!
